# React useState is not keeping the changes

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks

**Current Situation**

I am improving performance of the component called `ProductMain` using `React.memo()`. The `ProductMain` is containing `ProductComponent` that is list. And I am passing every single product information such as name and qty also `handleChangeQty` method to the `ProductComponent` as a `props`. To render `ProductComponent` separately, I am using `React.memo` with custom comparator method `areEqual`

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  const prevLocation = prevProps.product.locations
  const nextLocation = nextProps.product.locations
  let isEqual = true
  if(prevLocation.length !== nextLocation.length) return false 
  else
    for (let i = 0; i < nextLocation.length; i++) {
      if (nextLocation[i].adjustedQty !== prevLocation[i].adjustedQty)
        isEqual = false
    }
  return isEqual
}

const ProductComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ product, productIndex, onQtyChange, onFocusChange }) => {   
   const handleQtyChange = newValue => {
      onQtyChange(locationIndex, location.onHandQty, newValue)
   }
   return(<React.Fragment>
   //some button that can change the qty 'onClick'={handleQtyChange}
    </React.Fragment>)
}

export default React.memo(ProductComponent, areEqual)
```

From the `ProductComponent` when I change the qty, `handleChangeQty` function will be working in the `ProductMain`.  `ProductMain` has a `useState` hook `visibleProduct`. Every time `handleQtyChange` method works, I am updating the `visibleProducts` using setter function.

**Problem is**

In the `areEqual` method, I am comparing previuos props with next props. If these are identical, function returning true and `ProductComponent` won't be re-rendering. And Its working as expected, re-rendering only changed component. But `visibleProducts` is not consistently keeping the changes. For example at the very beginning

```
`visibleProduct = [{productId: 001, qty:0},{productId: 002, qty: 0}]`
```

After the `handleQtyChange` works, `visibleProduct` state changed to

```
`visibleProduct = [{productId: 001, qty:1},{productId: 002, qty: 0}]`
```

then I again, I changed the

```
`visibleProduct = [{productId: 002, qty: 1}]`
```

the previous value set back to initial value like `{productId: 001, qty:0},{productId: 002, qty: 1}`

It causes the re-rendering in the child component, and not keeping the previous changes.

Hope you understand well.
I tried to explain more detailed. Sorry for my language.

Comment: `areEqual` returns true if `prevLocation.length !== nextLocation.length`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for revealing the bug